# How i can get a random user from my firebase user list?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm developing a app and need get a random user from my firebase user list. Whenever a user registers, the system updates the user count on an especific node. So, I draw a number from 1 to the total user. And now, how do I select a user based on that number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your users are stored in a /users node with keys of their uid and assuming the uid's are ordered (which they always are), there are several options.

1) Load all of the users from the /users node into an array and select the one you want via it's index. Suppose we want the 4th user:

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let allUsersArray = snapshot.children.allObjects
    let thisUserSnap = allUsersArray[3]
    print(thisUserSnap)
})
```

While this works for a small amount of users, it could overwhelm the device if you have say, 10,000 users and lots of data stored in each node.

2) Create a separate node to just store the uid's. This is a significantly smaller dataset and would work the same way as 1)

```
uids
  uid_0: true
  uid_1: true
  uid_2: true
  uid_3: true
  uid_4: true
  uid_5: true
  uid_6: true
  uid_7: true
```

3) Reduce the size of your dataset further. Since you know how many users you have, split the dataset up into two sections and work with that.

using the same structure as 2)

```
let uidNode = self.ref.child("uids")

let index = 4 //the node we want
let totalNodeCount = 8 //the total amount of uid's
let mid = totalNodeCount / 2 //the middle node

if index <= mid { //if the node we want is in the first 1/2 of the list
    print("search first section")

    let q = uidNode.queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(index) )

    q.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let array = snapshot.children.allObjects
        print(array.last) //the object we want will be the last one loaded
    })
} else {
    print("search second section")

    let q = uidNode.queryLimited(toLast: UInt(index) )

    q.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let array = snapshot.children.allObjects
        print(array.first) //the object we want will be the first one loaded
    })
}
```

this method only returns 1/2 of the list so it's a much more manageable amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about your authenticated users, the only way to retreive a list of them is by calling the corresponding [admin function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and applying your logic to it afterwards.

Another way could be writing a [trigger for your authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onCreate) and store the userId with an incrementing number (and maybe save a totalUser field), then you only need to generate a random number and access said user.

Comment: It's fairly common practice to store users data in a /users node with the uid as the key for each user (see my answer) so there would be some options to get authenticated user data. The problem with the second suggestion is what if user 3 is deleted - that would leave a hole in the sequential list 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6 and then if a random number is generated, 3 for example, it breaks. This is one of the reasons array's should be avoided in NoSQL databases.